# How to get the number of times a particular URL has been shared on Google+?

Tags: php, google-plus

I'm using the [Google+ Share Link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink) on my website to let visitors share a particular page on Google+

For example:

`https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://example.com`

How can I get the number of times a particular URL has been shared?

**Please note:** I'm not trying to get the number of times a page has been +1'd.

Comment: `<a onlick="countThisSomehow();" href="...">Share</a>`

Comment: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/track-social-media-shares-link/

Comment: Thanks for the idea, although a click such as that doesn't guarantee an actual share took place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track the number of shares using [Google+ Ripples](https://plus.google.com/ripple/details?url=google.com) ([about](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1713320?hl=en)). However, there currently does not exist an official API and possibly never will.

Parse for the number of shares using [this snippet](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/get-google-share-count-url/):

```
$shares_url = 'https://plus.google.com/ripple/details?url='. $url;
$response = file_get_contents( $shares_url );
$shares_match = preg_match('@<div[^0-9]*([0-9]+) public share[s]?\.</div>@',$response,$matches);
if (!empty($matches)) {
    $shares = $matches[1];
} else {
    $shares = 0;
}
echo $shares;
```

Note the regex tries to specify the number as closely as possible, since there might also be a comment on the right hand side of the page saying something like

> 10 public shares by me!

which would otherwise also match.

Comment: This is a neat solution but reading the notes on the page you link to doesn't give me confidence in it continuing to work going forward. For example: "Note: Take this example at face value. It’s an unofficial method, and there are no guarantees it will work tomorrow"

Comment: Although this works when shares exist, if no shares exist a PHP debug error is thrown

Comment: Answer updated. I figured catching an empty result would not have to be part of the answer. Also added remark about the non-existing API.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Another problem I've spotted (this time with the preg_match() function). If there is only one page share then the text on the page reads "1 public share". Note it isn't plural, resulting in 0 being echo'd.

Comment: Do you have an example url? Is is really "1 page share" or "1 public share"?

Comment: Apologies, I should have said "1 public share". Note, the regex is looking for public shares (plural). I've updated my comment

Comment: Thanks for updating. I'll be able to award the bounty in ~20 hours

Comment: Good point, this actually got me thinking about the problem of matching comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63112/discussion-between-andy-and-henrywright).